# Segmentation Fault:11 in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C that replaces a number in a char* called "template" with a string, but I continually get a Segmentation Fault: 11 error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *rep_str(const char *s, const char *old, const char *new1){
    char *ret;
    int i, count = 0;
    int newlen = strlen(new1);
    int oldlen = strlen(old);

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (strstr(&s[i], old) == &s[i]){
            count++;
            i += oldlen - 1;
        }
    }
    ret = (char*)malloc(i + count * (newlen - oldlen));
    if (ret == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    i = 0;
    while (*s){
        if (strstr(s, old) == s){ //compare the substring with the newstring
            strcpy(&ret[i], new1);
            i += newlen; //adding newlength to the new string
            s += oldlen;//adding the same old length the old string
        } else {
        ret[i++] = *s++;
        }
    }
    ret[i] = '\0';

    return ret;
}

char* madlib_by_numbers(char* temp, int word_count, char* words[]){
    char* numbers[] = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
    int tempSize = strlen(temp);

    for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++){
        if (isdigit(temp[i])){
            for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(char*)); j++){
                temp = rep_str(temp, numbers[j], words[j]); //it makes it to this line, but never gets to assert()
            }
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

int main() {
  char* temp1 = "The 1 0 likes to 2 in the moonlight.";
  char* words[] = {"git", "brilliant", "swim"};
  char* result = "The brilliant git likes to swim in the moonlight.";
  int stringLength = strlen(result);

  char* test = madlib_by_numbers(temp1, 3, words);
  assert(strncmp(test, result, stringLength) == 0);
  free(test);

  return 0;
}
```

and when I run the debugger, it simply says: `Segmentation Fault: 11`

What i just want to understand is where the segmentation fault error is coming from, I have the suspicion one of my loops is running too many times.

Comment: But where is your `main()` function?

Comment: **Where** do you get this error? What does the debugger say?

Comment: @Olaf it makes it to "temp = rep_str(temp, numbers[j], words[j])" and I get the correct result, but then I get the Segmentation Fault error and it never makes it to assert() in my main.

Comment: Not related, but: don't cast `void *` to pointers.

Comment: Either add lots of debug statements, add lots of logging, or use a debugger to see where our code runs off the rails.

Comment: Running in gdb, after you get a segfault, `backtrace` (or just `bt`) will list the stack and show you what it was doing when the segfault occurred.  (Other debuggers worth anything will have a similar feature.) This can quickly locate such a problem. Be sure to _compile_ your program with the `-g` option.

Comment: `malloc(i + count * (newlen - oldlen))` --> `malloc(i + count * (newlen - oldlen) + 1);`

Comment: suggest using `const char *` whenever you initialize apointer with a string literal, to avoid accidentally writing to a string literal. In this case `numbers`, `temp1`, `words` and `result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ret = (char*)malloc(i + count * (newlen - oldlen));
```

There are a few problems with this line of code.

- For a start, [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (or any `void *` that you're assigning to a variable of different pointer type, or vice versa).
- If you intended to allocate space to store a string, where's the string-terminating `'\0'` going to go? You need to realise that for an empty `old` string, this will be `malloc(0)` and zero bytes is not enough to store an empty string.
- There's also a problem if you expect that `old` may be a substring of `new` (for example, you're replacing `"0"` with `"hell0"`). You'll need to tweak your algorithm to handle this problem. I'll leave that as a challenge for you to attempt :)

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++){
    if (isdigit(temp[i])){
        for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(char*)); j++){
            temp = rep_str(temp, numbers[j], words[j]); //it makes it to this line, but never gets to assert()
        }
    }
}
```

[users previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36274172/1989425) highlighted this code correctly, but not for the right reason... and so the solution he/she presented is wrong.

[`isdigit(temp[i])` may also cause segfaults for some inputs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877410/visual-c-debug-assertion-failed) I recommend using `isdigit((unsigned char) temp[i])` instead, in this case.

It's not valid to access `words[j]` where `word_count` is 3 and `j` is greater or equal to 3; you're accessing that array out of bounds.

You also need to be careful to `free` any memory you `*alloc` (while simultaneously not `free`ing memory that you don't `*alloc`). Forgetting to do the former won't cause crashes, but your program won't run happily; it'll use *heaps* of memory.

Consider something like this, instead:

```
temp = strdup(temp);
if (temp == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++){
    if (isdigit((unsigned char) temp[i])){
        for (int i = min(word_count, sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(char*)), j = 0; j < i; j++){
            char *new = rep_str(temp, numbers[j], words[j]);
            free(temp);
            temp = new;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issue with your code. However, the direct answer to your question is in this loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(char*)); j++){
        temp = rep_str(temp, numbers[j], words[j]);
}
```

You are calling `rep_str` for every digit while you mean call `rep_str` only if the digit in `temp` matches the corresponding digit in `numbers`. So add this conditional `if(strcmp(temp,numbers[j]) == 0)` right before the line `temp=...`. Then it'll solve your current problem.

The segfault is caused because there are only three elements in the `words` array. Your old loop indexes from 0 to 9 and fails when `j=3`, out of bound.

Also, delete the `free()` at the end of your program. `test` was never allocated and will cause a core dump.

Comment: `rep_str()` returns the result of a `malloc()`, which is possibly lost if `temp` is assigned more than once in `madlib_by_numbers()`. Maybe he's not calling `free()` enough, rather than too much. But the initial value of `temp` is a string literal, which can't be freed.