# How to put option for Sorting order in generic sort function

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, generics

THis is the compare function to be used in generic sort function. `x` and `y` are the elements to be compared for **generic sort** function.

```
int CompInt(void *x, void *y)
{
  int a = *((int*)x);
  int b = *((int*)y);
  int choice;
  printf("How do you want to sort ? \n\t1. Ascending \n\t2. Descending\n");
  scanf(" %d ", &choice);
  if(choice == 1)
    {
        if(a > b) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
  if(choice == 2)
    {
        if(a > b) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }
}
```

the calling function keeps calling `CompInt` function again and again without performing the compare. It keeps printing

```
how do you want to sort?`  
1. ascending 
2. descending
```

Is there any way I can put an option for Ascending or Descending?

this is how I call the function

```
if(compareFcn(*1st element*, *2nd element*) > 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you Should to Make a two function. If you select ascending.
   like this.

   ```
   int Ascending(void * a, void * b)  
   {  
       int inter_a = *((int*)(a)); int inter_b = *((int*)(b));

       if(inter_a > inter_b) 
            return -1;
       else 
            return 1;
   }

   int Descending(void * a, void * b)  
   {  
       int inter_a = *((int*)(a)); int inter_b = *((int*)(b));

       if(inter_a < inter_b) 
            return -1;
       else 
            return 1;
   }
   ```

   user can Select In Main Function. use Ascending, or Descending. And You call function what user select function.

   ```
   if(choice == 1)
   {
        Sort((void*)num, Ascending, sizeof(int), max);
   }
   else
   {
        Sort((void*)num, Descending, sizeof(int), max);
   }
   ```
2. And CompStr. I think you shold to use string.h.

CompStr has Problem. if a[i] == 'a', b[i] == 'D'. CompStr is think a[i] is comp first. you should to use like this.

```
    int CompStr(void *x, void *y)
    {
        char *a = (char*)x;
        char *b = (char*)y;
        int c1 = 0, c2 = 0, cmp = 0, i = 0;
        while(a[c1] != '\0') c1 += 1;
        while(b[c2] != '\0') c2 += 1;
        while((i < c1) && (i < c2))
        {  
            char compA = tolower(a[i]);
            char compB = tolower(b[i]);
            if(compA == compB)
            {
                 i++;
                 continue;
            }
            if(compA < compB)
            {
                 cmp = (-1);
                 break;
            }
            if(compA > compB)
            {
                 cmp = 1;
                 break;
            }
         }
         return cmp;
     }
```

and Test Code =

```
int main()
{
    //first exmaple.
    char * str1 = "Hallo.";
    char * str2 = "Hello.";

    //second exmaple.
    char * str3 = "What Does Fox Say?";
    char * str4 = "IDOLM@STER";

    //third example.
    char * str5 = "Stack Overflow.";
    char * str6 = "Stack Overflow.";

    int result = CompStr((void *)str1, (void *)str2);

    int result1 = CompStr((void *)str3, (void *)str4);

    int result2 = CompStr((void*)str5, (void*)str6);

    printf("1 : %d\n", result);
    printf("2 : %d\n", result1);
    printf("3 : %d", result2);
    return 0;
}
```

output is `1 : -1 2: 1 3: 0` Code is work well.

this code has problem.

```
case 4:
{
    printf("How many Strings you want to sort ? ");
    scanf("%d", &max);
    printf("Enter the strings\n");
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) scanf(" %s", str[i]);
    Sort((void*)str, CompStr, sizeof(char), max);
    printf("Sorted elements are are - \n");
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) printf(" %s\n", str[i]);
    break;
}
```

you want compare string. but sizeof element is just 1 byte. and you`re code can`t compile.

```
void *mem_copy(void *dest, const void *src, unsigned int n)
{
    int i;
    char* newsrc = (char*)src;
    char* newdest = (char*)dest;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    newdest[i] = newsrc[i];
}
```

i use compile VS 2017, you write return type is void *, but function is dosen`t return. is right code? please modified code compile well.

Comment: it's not working man..  here's the input `hey  how  are  you  surjt`  and here's the output `ehy  how  are  you  surjit`

Comment: Where is not Working?

Comment: I think not problem compStr. can you write you`re sort algorithm?

Comment: I add Test Code. please see.

Comment: I get [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877410/visual-c-debug-assertion-failed) when I test your `CompStr` function.

Comment: You could probably try something like `int CompStr(void const *x, void const *y) { unsigned char *a = x, b = y; while (*a && tolower(*a) == tolower(*b)) a++, b++; return (tolower(*a) > tolower(*b)) - (tolower(*a) < tolower(*b)); }` mind you, there's no portable guarantee that alphabetical characters be ordered the way you might think as C doesn't *require* ASCII.

Comment: Are write `#Inlcude <ctype.h>`?